# How to call desgv from LAPACK

Tags: c++, lapack

**Update**

error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

**New update**

I tried to make an experimental function to test about dgesv, but it says it can't find -llapack now, which is weird because I installed it through yum.

I'm having some trouble calling dgesv from LAPACK. Currently, I've tried this:

```
extern "C"
{
    void dgesv(int *N, int *NRHS, double *A,
          int *LDA, int *IPIV,
          double *B, int *LDB, int *INFO);
}

dgesv(&lengthA, &widthF, A, &leadingDemA,
          permMat, B, &leadingDemB, &errorCheck);
```

The problem is even when I compile with `g++ program -llapack`, the compiler yells at me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error(s) do you get from the compiler? Unresolved symbol?

Comment: Well, I do get a problem by passing in those static arrays, but the thing also can't recognize desgv for some reason. The compiler says dgesv wasn't declared.

Comment: You should include the errors in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the code you posted. First the declaration of `dgesv` is missing the semi-colon. You are also passing `A`, `B` and `permMat` incorrectly. The brackets should only be used when the variables are declared or defined as below

```
char a[10];
void f(char a[]);
```

The following changes should take care of the compilation issues as long as the code you posted is the actual code you are using.

```
extern "C"
{
    void dgesv(int *lengthA, int *widthF, double *A,
        int *leadingDemA, double *permMat,
        double *B, int *leadingDemB, int *errorCheck); // <-- semi-colon
}

dgesv(&lengthA, &widthF, A, &leadingDemA, permMat, B, &leadingDemB, &errorCheck);
//                        ^^                    ^^  ^^
```

Comment: I'm kind of new when it comes to static arrays. I've only really dealt with dynamic ones until now. So when do you need the [] for static arrays?

Comment: When you declare them. `char a[4]` or `void f(char a[])`. When you pass the variable to a function or assign them to another variable the brackets can't be used.

Comment: It's still giving me an error about void value not being ignored at the spot of function call.

Comment: Knew you would figure it out ;)